# My custom attribute directive put on an element with ngFor does not work

Tags: angular, typescript

I will divide this problem into two perspectives, which are the user's perspective and the developer's perspective.

User's perspective:

When I highlight links and click on "Delete", not all of them go deleted. Only the first one gets deleted, and the others do not. Here are some screenshots as an example.

[image]

Once I click on "Delete", only the 'Apples' link gets removed. The tomatoes, for some reason, do not get removed. This is a problem, and I do not know how to fix it.

Here is the result that I do not want:

[image]

and when I click delete again, nothing happens.

Developer's perspective:
consider the following code

App Shopping List Template:

```html
 <app-shopping-edit></app-shopping-edit>
    <hr>
    <ul class="list-group">
      <!-- In the anchor tag, we toggle between the active class. The toggling between the active class
      works perfectly fine. However, I can't delete specific anchor tags  -->
      <a
        class="list-group-item"
        appToggleActiveClass
        style="cursor: pointer"
        *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients">
        {{ ingredient.name }} ({{ ingredient.amount }})
      </a>
    </ul>
```

Important part of Shopping List Edit Template:

```html
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" (click) = "deleteItems()">Delete</button>
```

Shopping List Edit TS:

```js
// this will complete the observable and we will do some logic in SHOPPING LIST after that
deleteItems() {
    this.shoppingListService.deleteShoppingIngredients.complete()
}
```

Shopping List Service:

```js
 // This is for shopping list Edit to let shopping list know that we want to delete
deleteShoppingIngredients = new Subject<String>()
```

Shopping List TS:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.subForRemoved = this.shoppingListSerivce.deleteShoppingIngredients.subscribe(
  (value) => {

  },
  (err) => {

  },
   // we complete the obserevable and we call the directive to delete our ingredients.
  () => {
    this.ToggleDirective.deleteIngredients()
  })
  }
```

Last but not least, we have the Toggle Class Directive

```js
deleteIngredients() {
  // We call this method so that any anchor tag that has a class of 'active' gets removed
  if (this.el.nativeElement.classList.contains("active")) {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'display', 'none')
  }
}
```

What's really happening is that not all anchor tags with the class of `active` have `display: none`. How can I make it so that whenever I click "Delete", the links with a class of `active` disappear? As you can see in the code, I tried using a directive to get access to all the anchor tags with the class of `active` but for some reason, it's not accessing all the anchor tags. Any clue on what I can do?

I'll provide my whole GitHub repo in case anyone wants to play around with it. Keep in mind only the shopping list service in services and the shopping list folder are important. That's if, you choose to play around with the repo.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The github repo https://github.com/yousefmarey12/CourseShoppingProject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that by using `@ViewChild` you only refer to the FIRST directive in your shopping list. You need to use `@ViewChildren` to refer to ALL directives instead.

You can easily see it in a simpler scenario: after the page loads, select **Tomatoes** and click **Delete**. Nothing really happens because the only directive in the code is **Apples**.

So, in **shopping-list.component.ts** instead of

```
@ViewChild(ToggleActiveClassDirective) ToggleDirective: ToggleActiveClassDirective;
```

do this:

```
@ViewChildren(ToggleActiveClassDirective) ToggleDirective: ToggleActiveClassDirective[];
```

And then in your `complete` block instead of:

```
this.ToggleDirective.deleteIngredients();
```

Do this:

```
this.ToggleDirective.forEach(directive => directive.deleteIngredients());
```